# Creating a dynamic map from set of Lat longs c#.net

Tags: c#, google-maps, polyline

I am doing a c#.net application in which i want to show a map(poly line) with dynamically fetched lat longs from database, I tried Google's reverse geocoding but i am stuck here to work it out,can any one please help me to find a right solution for my scenario

Comment: show some code where you stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need reverse geocoding for this. Since you have a set of latlng's that will fetched form the database, this is the scene that should be followed--

Suppose you have a Asp server button, in onClick event, load the latlng values from the database and store them in an array in code behind.

Then pass this array to a javascript function that will perform placing this markers on the map. You can have a look at ["this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351156/unable-to-get-update-panel-working-right) code where I have already provided the code. Hope it will help you out in moving forward.

Comment: Let me know if you have an issue

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, I am new to this Google maps and i am not even good at script as well, if you don't mind can you please help me to work it out, I just started this module can you please help me in detail,

Comment: Let me tell you that till 3 weeks ago I new nothing about working with the Gmaps API and Javascript. So all I did was reading this: [READ THIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). It dint take me more than 3 days to completely read the documentation and now I have got enough grip on the subject. So first take your time reading it completely in an order(you need to be patient though) and I assure you can easily achieve what you are trying for. Then you can come with an issue here and ill try what I can. Gud luck.